# APNs Keep http2 keep connection alive

Tags: php, curl, apple-push-notifications, http2

Given that I'm not a web developer, I'm working to implement a APNS push notifications sender script.
I currently watched over this php library [pushok](https://github.com/edamov/pushok).
My implementation is like this:

```
...
$payload = createPayload( $json['category'], $params, $threadId);
$client = new Client( $authprovider, production = true );
$notification = new Notification($payload, $token, 'alert'));
$client->addNotifications([$notification]);
$responses = $client->push();
...
```

I noticed that this library uses cURL under the hood to contact APNS servers and everything seems to work fine.
Being this code in a script everytime called, i wondered if curl keeps the HTTP2 connection alive as requested by Apple or if everytime it is created a new connection.
Library is setted to don't close connections, but i wandered, is this valid on a context of a oneshot script everytime?
Is there a way to keep the php Client object alive between exections?

Answer (score 0):

I think port 443 is used now

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns?language=objc

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203609

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/sending_push_notifications_using_command-line_tools?language=objc

I've been talking to Apple via the developer portal and so far this is all I know. I've now decided to just cherry pick and see what other devs that use APNS did to keep the deliveries successful. I asked this question too and now that I'm browsing the Apple-Push-Notifications tag, I see others are too.